# Eclipse/FDT closes imports when typing in a new import

Tags: eclipse, fdt

For example I type the following:

import shared.

And on the dot, it closes the imports forcing me to reopen the imports and continue typing. Is there a way to disable this? What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be disabled without completely disabling autocomplete.

With autocomplete, when a selection is made, FDT will use that and then return you to the editor so you can enter another keyword.

You shouldn't ever need to type an import with FDT. You can:

1) Use autocomplete on a class / type and have FDT auto import the class
2) Use Organize Imports
3) Use a quick fix to import the class.

See more here:

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Main_Page

Comment: I haven't seen FDT import things automatically. FDT doesn't know to import from shared sources as far as I can tell. Automatically folding the import statements makes no sense. Quick fixes is nice, but why do the manual imports need to broken?

Comment: I have been using FDT for years and written many KLOC, I have never manually typed in an import.  FDT scans your code and determines what imports your missing and will automatically add them for you - that is the what all major IDEs do.